# Error while installing jekyll and want to remove ruby related files on mac osx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, jekyll, rbenv

I was trying to install jekyll on my Mac(OS X 10.11.2) to start my blog with a static page, following this [instruction](http://nolboo.github.io/blog/2013/10/15/free-blog-with-github-jekyll/) (sorry it's written in Korean)

I think I made a mistake when I typed (I typed the wrong URL)

```
git remote add origin URL
```

I wanted to delete jekyll and restart from the beginning so I did,

```
gem uninstall jekyll
```

and

```
gem cleanup gems
```

then the error message showed up like this

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:318:in `to_specs': Could not find 'jekyll' (>= 0) among 26 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/MYNAME/.gem/ruby/2.0.0:/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0', execute `gem env` for more information
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:327:in `to_spec'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:64:in `gem'
from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:22:in `<main>'
```

I tried installing rbenv with homebrew and every solution I looked up for but nothing has changed.

Is removing all the ruby related files and reinstalling is the only way to solve this problem? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: What did you do to install Jekyll? `sudo gem install Jekyll` or just `gem install Jekyll`?

Comment: Your question is not enough to solve the problem. And document you linked is also not good for starting jekyll. Read document on [jekyll korean page](http://jekyllrb-ko.github.io/)

Comment: @Hoang Phan I did 
    'sudo gem install Jekyll' then the error message showed up like this 
    'ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.1/LICENSE', So I did 'sudo gem install jekyll'

Comment: @JaehyunShin thanks a lot, I will follow the document

Answer (score 2):

Okay, for your problem only try this:

```
sudo gem uninstall jekyll
```

The reason is you have installed this gem into sudo's gemset and tried to remove it from user's gemset. They are different.

Comment: I got it. I had no basic knowledge on that area.. just wanted run jekyll on gitgub. thanks for the answer.